# How to deal with memory stack overload

Tags: c#, image-processing, stack-overflow, emgucv

I am trying to programm an edge detection method. And I have used emgucv Image class. Since I need gray values I have declared it as

```
Image<Gray,float> MyImage = new Image<Gray,float>;
```

I select an image and assign its pixel values into MyImage as

```
public void selectImage()
          { 
               OpenFileDialog opp = new OpenFileDialog();
              if (opp.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
              {                 
                   MyImage = new Image<Gray,float>(opp.FileName);
                  InputArray = new Image<Gray, float>(opp.FileName);
                  Convert.ToString(MyImage);
                  pictureBox1.Image = MyImage.ToBitmap();                
              }             
          }
```

When I click on edge detection button it calls the main recursive function

```
private void detect_edges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
           hueckel_operator(1, 1);
        }
```

This operator repeats itself with 5pixel intervals. In other words I apply it on x axis by incrementing x parameter by 5 and at the end of the row I increment y axis by 5 and so on.

In hueckel_operator, the function "a()" which calculates again a very heavy formula is being called 8 times. Here is the a() function

```
 public double a(int j,  int counter6,  int counter7)
            {

                for (int II = 0; II <= j ; II++)
                {
                    for (KK = 1; KK < 70; KK++)
                    {
                         x_value = input_i_x(KK); //this function brings the x coordinate
                         y_value = input_i_y(KK); // this function brings the y coordinate

                result += HueckelDisk(x_value,y_value,j) * MyImage[x_value+counter6, y_value+counter7].Intensity;
                //MyImage.Dispose();
                    }
                }                           
                return result;
            }
```

But the problem is approximately at the coordinate (75,5) it throws a stack overflow exception. I debugged it with performance analyse and MyImage seems to eat all memory. You probably wants to see recursive function but since it is too big I can not put it here and I am sure that recursive function (hueckel_operator()) can not reach terminating condition since I found out how many times it has been called. What I want is to find out if there is another way to calculate "result" in a more efficient way.

My other question is that, object MyImage is used in function a() 69*j times and does it mean that it allocates memory space 69*j times whenever a() is called?

During my desperate tries, I have declared and defined almost every variable as global in order to reduce the memory usage because I have thought otherwise whenever hueckel_operator() and a() are called, local variables would allocate extra memory in stack over and over, is it a good or necessary approach?

I use 4 very nested and heavy functions and I don't use any class. Would it be the main problem? To be honest I don't see anything here to convert into class.

I know, I have asked too many questions but I am really desperate right now. I am reading articles since some weeks and I guess I need a kick start. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stack overflow exception doesn't really have much to do with memory usage - it's from *stack* usage.   In your case, a recursive call.

Recursion can only go so deep until the stack is exhausted.  Once that happens, you get your stack overflow.

If you are *not* in an unbounded recursion but you need to go deeper, you can specify the stack size when you create a thread, and run your recursive function on that:

```
var stackSize = 10000000;
var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartDetection), stackSize);
```

However, the default size is 1MB - which is quite a bit for most tasks.   You may want to verify your recursion is in fact not unbound, or that you can't reduce or remove it.

Comment: Ok this seems to solve my problem, but I have to read about it first because I don't know where to put it or what to write instead of "Start Detection"(probably name of the function). I also would prefer to revise my algorithm but I really don't have time and I don't know maybe it is not unbounded as you said

Comment: Yes `StartDetection` in my example is the name of some function (probably would simply have one line: `hueckel_operator(1, 1);`)